# How do I display a <p> on screen when the user clicks

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am making a random name generator, I am wanting to display a random name when ever the user clicks on a button. But when ever the user clicks on the button at the moment, my content just briefly flashes on screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grand National 2016 Randomizer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="row intro">
            <div class="small-centered medium-uncentered medium-6 large-7 columns">
            <h1>Grand National 2016</h1>
            <div id="submit">
                <form method ='post'>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
                </form>
            </div>
        <p>
        <?php
            $horses = array();

            // pushing all the runners of the 2016 Grand National
            array_push($horses, "Many Clouds");
            array_push($horses, "MaSilviniaco Conti");
            array_push($horses, "First Lieutenant");
            array_push($horses, "Wonderful Charm");
            array_push($horses, "Ballynagour");
            array_push($horses, "O'Faolains Boy");
            array_push($horses, "Gilgamboa");
            array_push($horses, "On His Own");
            array_push($horses, "The Druids Nephew");
            array_push($horses, "Triolo D'Alene");
            array_push($horses, "Rocky Creek");
            array_push($horses, "Sir Des Champs");
            array_push($horses, "Holywell");
            array_push($horses, "Shutthefrontdoor");
            array_push($horses, "Soll");
            array_push($horses, "Buywise");
            array_push($horses, "Boston Bob");
            array_push($horses, "Aachen");
            array_push($horses, "Morning Assembly");
            array_push($horses, "Double Ross");
            array_push($horses, "Goonyella");
            array_push($horses, "Ucello Conti");
            array_push($horses, "Unioniste");
            array_push($horses, "Le Reve");
            array_push($horses, "Gallant Oscar");
            array_push($horses, "Onenightinvienna");
            array_push($horses, "The Last Samuri");
            array_push($horses, "Kruzhlinin");
            array_push($horses, "Rule The World");
            array_push($horses, "Just A Par");
            array_push($horses, "Katenko");
            array_push($horses, "Vics Canvas");
            array_push($horses, "Black Thunder");
            array_push($horses, "Ballycasey");
            array_push($horses, "Hadrian's Approach");
            array_push($horses, "Vieux Lion Rouge");
            array_push($horses, "Pendra");
            array_push($horses, "Saint Are");
            array_push($horses, "Home Farm");
            array_push($horses, "The Romford Pele");
            array_push($horses, "Knock House");
            array_push($horses, "Bishops Road");
            array_push($horses, "Pineau De Re");
            array_push($horses, "Alvarado");
            array_push($horses, "Highland Lodge");
            array_push($horses, "Maggio");
            array_push($horses, "Perfect Candidate");
            array_push($horses, "Present View");

            //sorting Array
            sort($horses);

            // Randomly select a winner!
            $counter = count($horses) - 1;
            $random = rand(0, $counter);

            print $horses[$random]; 
        ?>
      </p>
    </div>
</section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 99vh; }

  .hero:before {
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ccffdd, black);
    opacity: .8; }

  .hero .intro {
    padding: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); }
  .hero h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center; }
  .hero p {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
    .hero h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 2.5rem; }
    .hero p {
      color: gold;
      text-align: center; 
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      display: none;} 
      #submit {
        text-align: center;
        }}
```

Here is my Jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        $('p').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to use `preventDefault();`

Comment: why bother with having a form - it does nothing other than post an empty array ~ change the button to a standard button rather than a submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as easy as follow:

**Note:** I am not writing complete code just want to tell you what to do.

In your PHP file such as `index.php`:

```
<?php

// your data array
$horses = array("Many Clouds", "MaSilviniaco Conti" /* ... */);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
.
.
.
<a href="index.php">Get Random</a>
<p> <?=$horses[ rand(0, count($horses) - 1) ]?> </p>
.
.
.
```

It don't need anything else like jQuery and ... unless you are going to have some extra JavaScript functionality like retrieving the data from server-side by using xhr or manipulating the DOM on the client-side on the fly or interacting with user actions.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the element that you are clicking on is actually a `<input type='submit' />` button and is causing the page to be submitted / posted to the server.

If you want to prevent this default behavior from occurring you can use the [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function within your jQuery call :

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function(e){
        // Stop the default behavior (submission)
        e.preventDefault();
        $('p').show();
    });
});
```

It should be noted that this may cause your `<form>` to not be submitted as expected, so your usage may need to be adjusted if you still need that to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below. It is happening because the form submit and refreshes the page. You need to use the e.preventdefault like below

```
 <script>
 $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $( "<div>" )
   .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
   .appendTo( "#log" );
```

});